# Predicate logic. Check if I have done this correctly

Tags: logic

I need someone to verify if I have translated a sentence into predicate logic correctly.

**Given predicates**:

- Empty(x) : the list x is empty
- Sorted(x) : the list x is sorted in ascending (not decreasing) order
- x < y : number x is smaller than number y
- At(x, i, y) : the list x contains the number y on index i

The start index begins always at zero in a list.
[41, 19, 7, 5, 2, 5], i.e. the number 41 is at index 0 in the list, number 19 is at index 1, and so on.

The sentence(Updated): **If it is for a non-empty list holds if i < j, then we know that the number on index j in the list is not less than the number on index i, then the list is sorted.**

My translation: **¬Empty(L)∧((i < j)∧At(L, i, p)∧At(L, j, q) → ¬(q < p))→Sorted(L)**

Comment: Sorry, I can't understand the sentence you are supposed to translate.  It does not appear to be English.

Comment: Karl, if the sentence was originally in another language, perhaps you can include it in that language.

Comment: Sorry. This is a hard sentence to translate.

A new attempt: **If it is for a non-empty list holds if i < j, then we know that the number on index j in the list is not less than the number on index i, then the list is sorted.**

Comment: Karl, I still can't understand this sentence. If you wish, perhaps someone here can translate it for you. http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/107/faq-for-math-stackexchange/4384#4384

Comment: I asked my friend and he said that my formula is correct. 
Thank you very much anyway :)